# Disable Property in Design View Property Grid

Tags: .net, winforms, user-controls, propertygrid, design-view

I want to expose some properties in my custom control. I require to get input for three parameters that I expose as `Browsable` properties from the control. Based on input for one property the other two might not be required. How can I disable/hide the properties that are not required based on selection for first property?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, with a little reflection, you can achieve this:

```
public class TestControl : Control {
  private string _PropertyA = string.Empty;
  private string _PropertyB = string.Empty;

  [RefreshProperties(RefreshProperties.All)]
  public string PropertyA {
    get { return _PropertyA; }
    set {
      _PropertyA = value;

      PropertyDescriptor pd = TypeDescriptor.GetProperties(this.GetType())["PropertyB"];
      ReadOnlyAttribute ra = (ReadOnlyAttribute)pd.Attributes[typeof(ReadOnlyAttribute)];
      FieldInfo fi = ra.GetType().GetField("isReadOnly", BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance);
      fi.SetValue(ra, _PropertyA == string.Empty);
    }
  }

  [RefreshProperties(RefreshProperties.All)]
  [ReadOnly(true)]
  public string PropertyB {
    get { return _PropertyB; }
    set { _PropertyB = value; }
  }
}
```

This will disable PropertyB whenever PropertyA is an empty string.

Found this article at [the Code Project](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/152945/Enabling-disabling-properties-at-runtime-in-the-Pr) that described this process.